# Why does "take" change datatype in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function which takes elements from a list and returns them.

Pretty simple I thought. But when using "take" in for example: `take 2 [1.2,3,4]`

it returns: `[1.2,3.0]` when I actually want `[1.2, 3]`

I thought for creating a function that goes through the list and cuts unnecessary decimals but I can't get my head around it seeing haskell doesn't accept my comparison with x & round(x) in

```
function :: [a] -> [a]
function(x:xs)
 if x == round(x) = round(x):function xs
 else x:function xs
```

So A: Are there any simpler solutions?
B: Why can't haskell compare x with round(x)?

Comment: Have you tried `[1.2, 3]` without the `take`? If not, I recommend you do. It isn't `take`'s fault at all.

Comment: It looks like the syntax you're trying to use to define `function` is incorrect. The expression `x == round(x)` is perfectly fine, but the syntax would look like this: `function(x:xs) | x == round(x) = round(x):function xs; function(x:xs) = x:function xs`

Comment: @TannerSwett The expression `x == round x` is fine, but there is no concrete type (in the standard libraries) that you could give to `x` that would make it type-correct.

Answer (score 11):

You say, "I actually want `[1.2, 3]` [and not `[1.2, 3.0]`]". I interpret this to mean that you want a list that contains `Float`s or the like for fractional numbers and `Int`s or the like for numbers without a fraction part.

You can't have this.

All lists in Haskell are homogeneous: every element has the same type.

There are some things you can do; for example, you can have tagged unions, the canonical example being `Either`. So

```
[Left 1.2, Right 3] :: [Either Double Integer]
```

would be fine; but you need to explicitly tag each element.

This is also more or less the answer to why `x == round x` doesn't work: the `(==)` operator takes two arguments of the same type; whereas typically `round` cannot return a value of the same type as its argument. You might like `properFraction` instead:

```
> properFraction 3
(3,0.0)
> properFraction 1.2
(1,0.19999999999999996)
```

You can check the second part of this to determine whether your number is a whole number or not (and when it is, the first part will be the result of `round`).

Answer (score 6):

`take` does not change the type of list elements. Start up GHCi and follow along. My prompt is `>>>`.

```
>>> :t [1.2,3,4]
[1.2,3,4] :: Fractional t => [t]
```

This says the list elements have some `Fractional` type.

```
>>> :t [1.2,3.0,4.0]
[1.2,3.0,4.0] :: Fractional t => [t]
```

GHCi says the same thing here as well. What is going on?

```
>>> :t 2
2 :: Num t => t
>>> :t 2.0
2.0 :: Fractional t => t
```

A number literal without a decimal is inferred to have some `Num` type. A number literal with a decimal is inferred to have some `Fractional` type. For two elements to be in the same list, they must have the same type. What is the common type for `2` and `2.0`?

```
>>> :t 2 `asTypeOf` 2.0
2 `asTypeOf` 2.0 :: Fractional a => a
```

All `Fractional` types are `Num` types, and so the common type for `2` and `2.0` is some `Fractional` type.

```
>>> [1.2,3,4]
[1.2,3.0,4.0]
```

We can see from the printing of the list that all the elements have been inferred as a `Fractional` type. This defaults to `Double`.

To remove unnecessary decimals from a list you will have to be more specific about what type you want this list to have. A list of `Int` has no decimals and a list of `Double` always has decimals. A single list cannot have both `Int` and `Double` typed elements.